# Angularjs date display

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

Hi I am trying to figure out how to display date properly using angularjs.

My system returns the date in this fromat

```
 c_date="\/Date(1151470800000-0500)\/"
```

I dont know what format is it. 
I am displaying it

```
 using <span>{{pro.c_date | date:'medium')</span>
```

When i run this i get date printed in same format 
              "/Date(1151470800000-0500)/"

Can anyone suggest how to fix this so date can be displayed properly.
Thanks

Comment: c_date is in a wrong format (needs to be formatted either as Date object, milliseconds (string or number) or various ISO 8601 datetime string formats (e.g. yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ and its shorter versions like yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ, yyyy-MM-dd or yyyMMddTHHmmssZ))

Comment: This is Jason date format, db is sending this value using jason date format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the date that you're trying to use is a invalid date or maybe I don't know what format are the system using.

The problem is that angular.js requires a data object for can format it. Not a date string.

I suppose that the date is 1151470800000 miliseconds since the epoch least 0500 for adjust hours or something.

If this is correct, you only need to make c_date a Date object before pass to view.

```
c_date = "\/Date(1151470800000-0500)\/";
var the_date = eval("new "+c_date.replace(/\\|\//g, ''));
```

http://jsbin.com/zuwizoxe/3/

Regards!